# Appcenter SDK vs react-native-code-push

Tags: react-native, code-push, visual-studio-app-center, react-native-code-push

Do we need to link Appcenter to use react-native-code-push? Is Appcenter only needed if you want analytics, crash reports, push etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-native-code-push` started out as a standalone tool and continues to be able to be used as such. If you are using it standalone you will have to use the CLI. If you use `AppCenter` from Microsoft they have at least some UI built into their platform for code push that you can utilize.

Comment: There is currently no UI for Code Push in AppCenter. It should be coming next year.. You can create an app, but the rest requires the CLI